# Python method to try another arbitrary method until it runs without error?

Tags: python, keyword-argument, try-except

I am trying to create a method to run an arbitrary method passed to it until it runs without errors.

```
    def multiTry(method, sArg, **kwargs):
        """
        Attempt a specified method until it runs without error.
        Inputs:
          method:  method to be tried until it runs without error
          sArg:  string of all arguments to be passed to method
          kwargs:  all arguments needed for method
        """

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            eval(key = value)

        bDone = False
        while not bDone:
            try:
                method(eval(sArg))
                bDone = True
            except:
                pass

    multiTry(method=methodToRun, sArg="myString, myNum", myString="hello", myNum=5)
```

The goal is to repeatedly try:

```
methodToRun("hello", 5)
```

...until it runs successfully, where `methodToRun` is any method and the arguments are any arguments.

I understand both the eval statements are used incorrectly. Probably there is a completely different way to achieve the same goal? I have a number of methods to individually run until successful, and would not like to place every one of them in in-line try-except blocks.

Comment: In python you can pass a list or tuple as positonal arguments to a function, and a dict as arbitrary keyword arguments like `method(*args, **kwargs)`. These can be any two variables you want of the proper types (e.g. in your case `method(*sArgs)` but it should be a list of arguments not a string.

Comment: It's interesting because you already have `**kwargs` in your function signature. As you can see there is a symmetry. You can use the same syntax when *calling* a function as well. No need to use `eval` for this (which as you noted you're not using correctly anyways).

Comment: For reference here's [a version of this](https://gitlab.com/sagemath/sage/blob/develop/build/sage_bootstrap/util.py#L20) I wrote a little while back, but you can find many others on the web. In my case I opted not to take `*args` or `**kwargs` directly for the function being wrapped, as they might conflict with the keyword arguments to my `retry()` function itself. Instead you can "curry" a function along with its arguments into a parameterless function, e.g. by using a `lambda` statement or [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close. Something like this should do what you need:

```
def multiTry(method, **kwargs):
    while(1):
        try:
            method(**kwargs)
            return
        except:
            pass

multiTry(method=methodToRun, myString="hello", myNum=5)
```

Comment: Hard to say for sure but I think they might also want positional arguments with `*args`

Comment: That's what I thought too at first, but it looks like the `sArg` parameter is being used to define what kwargs to expect, rather than as an actual arg. This question smells a bit like an XY problem to me, but my solution here can be used as a stepping off point at least

Comment: Ah right, I see what you're saying. And yes, I agree.

Comment: Awesome, this works for me.  I didn't realize reusing the kwargs dict would be that straightforward.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

No need to reinvent the wheel here,  this a pretty common requirement,  I recommend you use the tenacity library  https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/  lots of options on handling retrys with a nice interface. Its a fork of the older retrying libary: https://pypi.org/project/retrying/